# Get unicode characters and siunitx \ang{} to work together

Tags: fontspec, unicode, lmodern

**Code**:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{✓}{\textfallback{✓}}
\newunicodechar{✗}{\textfallback{✗}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\ang{4} ✓ ✗
\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image: Output where the degrees symbol does not work.]

**Problem**:

When I remove `\usepackage{lmodern}`, all symbols work, but I want the `lmodern` font.
[image: Output where all symbols work.]

This part defines fallback characters which are not present in lmodern:

```
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{✓}{\textfallback{✓}}
\newunicodechar{✗}{\textfallback{✗}}
```

When I remove that part, the degree symbol starts working again.
[image: Output where only the degree symbol works.]

**Question**:

Why are these two things in conflict? Clearly `lmodern` is capable of displaying the degree symbol. How can it be fixed?

Comment: You *do* get the Latin Modern font without `\usepackage{lmodern}` (which should not be loaded with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't load `lmodern` along with `fontspec`.

The default font, when `fontspec` is loaded, *is* Latin Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}

\newunicodechar{✓}{\textfallback{✓}}
\newunicodechar{✗}{\textfallback{✗}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ang{4} ✓ ✗

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]